# Which keyboard shortcut for Resharper "Find Usages"

Tags: resharper

Which is the predefined Resharper shortcut for "Find Usages"?

Or if there is no one by default, which one do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

**Shift+F12** rules for ergonimicity.

Answer (score 0):

Default shortcut is Alt + F7.
You can see it in the menu, if you right click on an identifier

Answer (score 0):

`Shift + Alt + F12` also works fine.